# compare two strings leaving out dates present in them

Tags: oracle

On updating of record in a table, I am updating "note" column of that record with relevant information. That also contains date and time of updating along with specific information. 
On each update I am checking for previous "note" column value, if new values to be updated in "note" Colum is same as already existing values in "note" column, it shouldn't update it.

Scenario 1 : First time below value will be inserted in "note" column

```
[2015-11-30 04:03 by ]:(ENG)– Test Data Test Data(All companies) - Update.[1234]
```

Scenerio 2 : If same value is inserted in "note" column

```
[2015-11-30 05:05 by by ]:(ENG)– Test Data Test Data(All companies) - Update.[1234]
```

Now on updation I am comparing like below :

```
    IF NVL(:old.notes, '-') != NVL(:new.notes,'-') THEN

//code here         



    END IF;
```

As you can see, even if two simultaneous values are same, they will differ because of date. How do I ignore date in comparison

Each new record to be inserted will be separated by new line at the end.

Comment: could you compare just a substring of the note?

Answer (score 0):

Given your example it looks like you are interested in the part of the string that follows the first square closing bracket ]. Using substr, instr functions  will get that part of the string for you.

Example.

```
declare
   l_string varchar2(100);

    begin
       l_string := '[2015-11-30 05:05 by by ]:(ENG)– Test Data Test Data(All companies) - Update.[1234]';

       l_string := substr(l_string, instr(l_string, ']') + 1);

       dbms_output.put_line(l_string);
    end;
```

With the resulting strings you can do your comparison.